# Не верно удаляются символы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Скрипт удаляет из строки символы из списка

```
function withoutCyr(input) {
var value = input.value;
var re = /а|б|в|г|д|е|ё|ж|з|и|ё|к|л|м|н|о|п|р|с|т|у|ф|х|ц|ч|ш|щ|ъ|ы|ь|э|ю|я|'|"|\?|<|>|\/|\\|:|;|!|#|%|\]|\[|&|^|\*|$|!|\+| /gi;
if (re.test(value)) {
value = value.replace(re, '');
input.value = value;
}
}
```

Знак + удаляется только 2-й и последующие, 1й не удаляется

Comment: Что означает 2-ой и последующие удаляются, 1-ый не удаляется?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow вводишь ++++++++, должны все удаляться, + остаётся один

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так же нужно экранировать символы

`^` - соответствует началу строки
`$` - соответствует концу строки

аналогично другим уже экранированным символам: `\/`, `\]`, `\*`, `\+` и т.д.
будет выглядеть: `\^`, `\$`

для пример из комментария

```
... |\^|\+|\$| ...
```

Рабочий пример:

```js
var r = /(\^|\+|\$)/gi;

function change(s){
    document.getElementById('r').innerHTML = s.replace(r, "_replaced($1)_");
}
change('^+$');
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="change(this.value)" value="^+$"/>
<div id="r"></div>
```

Comment: написал так ... |^+$| ... не работает,можно пример?

Comment: @Rufex, обновил ответ

Answer (score 4):

Если аккуратно написать шаблон регулярного выражения, то все будет удаляться, как оно требуется.

Например,

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        "USE STRICT";
        var pattern = /[абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя'"\?<>\/\\:;!#%\]\[&\^\*\$\+]/gi;
        var s = "++++++++";
        alert("\"" + s + "\"");
        s = s.replace(pattern, "");
        alert("\"" + s + "\"");
    };
</script>
```

Или, как подсказал **@Grundy**, литерал регулярного выражения может быть записан даже проще

```
var pattern = /[А-ЯЁ'"\?<>\/\\:;!#%\]\[&\^\*\$\+]/gi;
```

Comment: можно тогда и алфавит интервалом записать: `а-яё`

Comment: @Grundy Вообще-то, алфавит расположен не последовательно по порядку возрастания кодов.

Comment: если не ошибаюсь там только буква `ё` выбивалась. я не прав?

Comment: @Grundy Не знаю. Я так думаю, что могут быть захвачены некоторые другие символы, которые попадают в этот диапазон.

Comment: сейчас проверил, от `a` до `я` подряд идут без пробелов, только `ё` нет